# Best approach to feature engineering in natural language processing?

Tags: nlp, feature-extraction, n-gram, information-extraction, feature-engineering

I am trying to cluster a large corpus of documents and would like to also subsequently explain what characterises each cluster in terms of the most common shared keywords or key-phrases in each cluster. To make clustering feasible, I will use a dimensionality reduction method like for example LSA (SVD) or doc2vec.

I can see several possible paths to the dimensionality reduced feature matrix:

1. POS-tagging, chunking (shallow parsing) for nounal phrases (NPs), TF-IDF, LSA (SVD)
2. n-grams, TF-IDF, LSA (SVD)
3. doc2vec all the way.

What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of these and perhaps other approaches? And what is ultimately the best way to go?